# How To Add Drop Down Of Specific Content Type Nodes Title And Ids

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Generally Created Two Content Type's :

1)Category.
2)Paragraph.

10 Nodes created in Category Content.

How To provide this node in drop down 'paragraph' content type nodes.

Please give suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want a drop down list of nodes of certain types? What are you using it for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using drupal 7, then you should install the following modules: [entity api](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Then go to paragraph manage fields page, under admin/structure/types/manage/paragraph/fields and add a new field.

for "Type of data to store", choose **Entity Reference**. and for "Form element to edit the data", choose **Select list**.

Under "Field settings", choose "Target type" -> **Content**. and from "Target bundles" choose **Category** (the content type you need to reference)

Click "Save field settings". and you are done.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose of your 'category content type' is to be used as drop down for other content type, then better make it vocabulary/taxonomy instead of content type.

Otherwise in 'paragraph content type', add new field text/select and use php code to return keyed array of category titles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having CCK module enable 'Node Reference', otherwise install it. Then do the following:

1. Go to Content Type -> Edit Paragraph -> Manage fields.
2. Add a new field with 'node reference' as the Type of data to store.
3. In field configuration settings select 'Category' content type.
4. Save.
5. Go and create a new Paragraph content, you will see a drop down box listing all the category nodes for selection.

If you are using categories for labelling purpose, consider using taxonomy as mentioned by Neelam.